# Using data binary in Python requests

Tags: python, curl, request, python-requests

I am trying to represent the following curl statement in python:

```
curl --data-binary @sample.png --data project = 23423233 -H 'X-API-KEY: YOUR API KEY, User-Agent: AppName (name@example.com)' https://files.proofhub.com/files/upload
```

I have already done multiple post & get requests, however since this one uses the data option, I cannot get my head around how I would execute this using requests.

I will post my current code:

```
data = open(r"C:\Users\dlogan.CLEARDATA\Desktop\ProofHub Upload\test.txt",'rb')

create_headers = {'X-API-KEY': '', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': '@cleardata.co.uk'}

r = requests.post('https://cleardata.proofhub.com/files/upload', data=data, headers=create_headers)
```

Does anyone know how i'd go about including an file?

Comment: Have you tried just reading the file? `data = open(r"C:\Users\dlogan.CLEARDATA\Desktop\ProofHub Upload\test.txt",'rb').read()`

Comment: What happens when you run the code above?

Comment: @brunns This didn't work, same response.

Comment: @WillKeeling I get an API <Response [404]>, I will contact the Company to see what exactly this response is and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you're missing a trailing slash '/' on the end of the URL. Without the trailing slash the server seems to redirect to a non-existent page and you get the 404.

To fix, just add a trailing slash:

```
requests.post('https://cleardata.proofhub.com/files/upload/', data=data, headers=create_headers)
#                                               Add slash ^
```

Comment: This got rid of my 404 error, however I am now experiencing another problem where the request doesn't actually do anything. Thank you for your help, you technically solved the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to post your file as form data using the `files` argument.

```py
files = {'file': open(r"C:\Users\dlogan.CLEARDATA\Desktop\ProofHub Upload\test.txt",'rb')
} 
create_headers = {'X-API-KEY': '', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': '@cleardata.co.uk'}
r = requests.post('https://cleardata.proofhub.com/files/upload', files=files, headers=create_headers)
```

You'll need to get the file name right - I can't see the post form, so I don't know what should be.